# How to output TeX with FeynArts?

Tags: packages, latex, feyncalc

I've recently installed [FeynArts](https://feynarts.de/) since I can use mathematica to generate topologies and it comes with a set of commands to make diagrams in LaTeX. However, nowhere in the manual can I find a command to output the LaTeX code that will generate the corresponding diagram. Does this functionality exist, and if so, how do I use it?

Comment: You should really give links. But if you mean https://feynarts.de/ then it says **FeynArts produces publication-quality Feynman diagrams in PostScript or LaTeX in a format that allows easy customization.** I looked quickly and do not see how. Try to contact the package author?. But why do you need the Latex? Simply export the plot as pdf or even eps, and include that in you latex document. That is what I would do.

Comment: Thanks - I will add that link to the question. Unfortunately the output is poorly formatted in mathematica, so I'd like the latex code to be able to make it look better. I'll shoot the author an email.

Comment: There are special packages in Latex to make Feyn diagrams directly in Latex if that you want. [Feynman_diagrams](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Feynman_diagrams)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm familiar with those - I was just hoping I could code up my Lagrangian and out would pop some nice tex. I'll update the post if I get a response

Comment: This might be of some help. https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0012260.pdf The author shows how to export as postscript. He also shows the LaTeX form, though he didn't explicitly show how. The implication is that he passed an option to Paint to choose among a variety of output forms, the default being PS graphics. Try checking options for Paint and see if LaTeX shows up.

Comment: I took a look at the online manual. Take a look at section 5.1 "Things to do with the Paint Output" starting on page 37. There are 3 rendering functions, Export/Display/Show which accept output formats PS and TeX, though you need to use feynarts.sty for LaTeX to interpret the TeX output properly.